# RecyclerView won't scroll all the way down inside BottomSheetBehavior

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I am trying to create a bottom sheet that will contain view which when pressed and dragged changes `BottomSheetBehaviour` state. (moves with `bottomSheet`), under that view is `recyclerView` which contains items that may be readded/deleted after the layout was already created.

What I've achieved so far is to make the `recyclerView` scrollable, however it won't scroll all the way down if the `bottomSheet` is in STATE_SETTLING state (not fully open, at `peekHeight`) it will however when it's STATE_EXPANDED (at layout_height). I tried to set the height of recyclerView to wrap_content but it had no effect (also I've read it's not reccomended as well).

How do I allow the `recyclerView` to scroll all the way down while in `STATE_SETTLING` state?

This is the code :

Activity - Testing

```
public class Testing extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayout bottomSheetLayout;
private BottomSheetBehavior<LinearLayout> sheetBehavior;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    bottomSheetLayout = findViewById(R.id.bottomSheetLayout);
    sheetBehavior= BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetLayout);

    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter();
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                sheetBehavior.setDraggable(false);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                sheetBehavior.setDraggable(true);
            }

            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
}
```

}

Activity layout - activity_test

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_test_sheet"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Bottom Sheet layout - activity_test_sheet

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheetLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="300dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_25"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerView Adapter - RecyclerViewAdapter

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private final List<Integer> dataList;

public RecyclerViewAdapter() {
    this.dataList = Arrays.asList(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
}

public static class GeneralViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    public GeneralViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_rv_item,parent,false);
    return new GeneralViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    setLayout((GeneralViewHolder) holder);
}

private void setLayout(GeneralViewHolder holder) {
    holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red_06);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}
}
```

RecyclerView item - test_rv_item

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_30"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_40"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `RecyclerView` "which expands its height to the far bottom end of the `BottomSheet`" fully shows its content in the `BottomSheet` **Expanded state**.

But here you want to show its content fully in the Half Expanded state; which requires to decide what will be shown in the Expanded state at the bottom of the `RecyclerView`; in another meaning the `RecycerView` bottom edge won't be the same as the `BottomSheet` bottom end in the expanded state; because it already occupied the half expanded state.

If you don't want to add anything at the bottom, then to show the full content in the half expanded state, you have to fill the bottom gap with some padding that equals to the displacement expansion to get it from the half to the expanded state.

```
The height of this gap almost = Bottom sheet height - peekHeight
```

Applying that to your bottom sheet:

```
The height of this gap almost = 450dp - 300dp = 150dp
```

So, you need to add a bottom padding of 150dp to the `RecyclerView` to make its content fully visible at the `BottomSheet` half-expanded state; but make sure to disable the `clipToPadding`:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:paddingBottom="150dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    .... />
```

Note: I have no evidence of this formula rather than trail and error.